# Prompting Metamask window if user is not logged in?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am trying to get user wallet address. The problem is that if Metamask is not logged in, it won't show any message. The below code will log 3 but not 4 if user is not logged In. So no error or anything. I am trying to find out how I could show Metamask window asking user to log in.

```
if (window.ethereum) {
    console.log(2)
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {       
        console.log(3)
        await ethereum.enable();
        console.log(4)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(5)
        // User denied account access...
    }
}
```

I also checked opensea and uniswap and it seems they couldn't figure out that too. Opening new browser with Metamask installed but not logged it, it won't detect Metamask. On Uniswap clicking Connect Wallet doesn't do anything while on opensea it opens https://metamask.io/download/. Apparently there is no solution to this problem?

If no other solution, I was thinking to put this into code:

```
    console.log(3)
    var isLoggedIn = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!isLoggedIn){alert('Login into Metamask...')}
    },1000);
    await ethereum.enable();
    isLoggedIn = true;
```